# Inno setup asking for remove folder only if contain files

Tags: inno-setup

```
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
var
Infos : integer;
begin
  if DirExists(ExpandConstant('{app}\saves'))  then
  begin
  case CurUninstallStep of
    usUninstall:
      begin
        Infos := MsgBox('Do u want remove saves?', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO)
        if Infos = IDYES then
        begin
        DelTree(ExpandConstant('{app}') +'\saves', True, True, True);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;`
```

I want inno ask for remove save folder only if folder is non empty. It is possible at all?

Comment: Google your question before asking!

Comment: So how should look like the final code? I'm new in Inno and still learning. Thanks.

Comment: `if DirExists(ExpandConstant('{app}\saves')) and (not isEmptyDir(ExpandConstant('{app}\saves'))) then`

Comment: Thanks so much. This works perfectly :)